# Nginx domain points to wrong dir

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have two *www* directories in my nginx server. *Directory 1* and *directory 2*.

*Domain 1* one is configured to point to *directory 1* and works as expected.

*Domain2* is configured to point to *directory 2*, but instead points to *directory 1*.

**Domain 1 -> Directory 1**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/sarasaworks.com/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name sarasaworks.com www.sarasaworks.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

**Domain 2 -> Directory 2**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/snapdragonwellness.org/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name snapdragonwellness.org www.snapdragonwellness.org snapdragonwellness.com www.snapdragonwellness.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

Every thing looks exactly as it should, so I'm not quite sure what I should do to fix it...

Both directories have a dummy html file with unique hello world-like phrases to let me know everything works.

Comment: Use: `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to see the entire configuration that Nginx is reading and ensure that the two server blocks appear and that the `server_name` statement is an exact match of the 2nd domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked for a default server?
`grep default_server /etc/nginx/ -r -C 3`
maybe there is a catchall server block like

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/sarasaworks.com/html;
    server_name _;
}
```

If the 2 server blocks are in different files each of these files need to be linked to from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

you can check that with
`ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

Another thing I would try is running `sudo nginx -t` to see if there are any errors in the configurations.

Good start to troubleshoot those problems is also to run `sudo tail -f /var/log/access.log` or `sudo tail -f /var/log/error.log/` to see what's going on.
While this is running you can reload/try to access the URL and see the logs.

More details on the errors can help us help you.